# Стоит ли использовать _forceinline для функций, которые возвращают значения

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Подскажите, пожалуйста, настолько целесообразно помечать подобные функции спецификаиором _forceinline, если они вызываются каждые две секунды? И что компилятор подставит в месте вызова функции: возвращаемое значение или все тело функции?

```
FVector MakeRandomDirection(float minAngle,float maxAngle)
{
    FVector direction(0.f, 0.f, -1.f);

    const float randAngle = FMath::RandRange(minAngle,maxAngle);
    direction       = direction.RotateAngleAxis(randAngle,
                                                FVector(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));

    if (FMath::RandBool())
    {
        direction.Y *= -1;
    }

    return direction;
}
```

Comment: Все тело. Где ж он без тела сразу возьмет возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Вообще, откуда желание использовать здесь `__forceinline`? Я понимаю когда это совсем примитивная функция, а-ля `operator+(vec2, vec2)`, которая всего несколько чисел складывает, и хочется чтобы она в дебаге не тормозила, но здесь-то что-то более сложное. В релизе компилятор сам заинлайнит если нужно.